# Converting Map<key, value> to List<value>

Tags: list, dictionary, dart, flutter, type-conversion

I've been searching for a while without success. I am trying to convert a Map to a List (discarding key).

Sure, I can do

```dart
var addictionList = new List<AddictionDay>();
dataMan.forEach((String date, AddictionDay day) {
    addictionList.add(day);
});
```

but is there a more straight approach, like

```dart
var addictionList = dataMan.toList();
```

?

`map` function of Map doesn't seem to help a lot, because it accepts only `MapEntry<K2, V2>` as a param so it's a no go. Pretty surprised nobody asked this question before.

I was also thinking about new class extending Map, but right now I am just looking into some native way to do this, if it exists.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Do you need this or something more complicated?

```
  var _map = {1: 'one', 2: 'two', 3: 'three'};
  var values =_map.values.toList();
  print(values);
```

Result:

`[one, two, three]`

Answer (score 13):

Map class has the [entries](https://api.dartlang.org/stable/2.2.0/dart-core/Map/entries.html) property which returns the map entries as an iterable on which you can use the [map](https://api.dartlang.org/stable/2.2.0/dart-core/Iterable/map.html) function to generate the list of items you need.

```
var addictionList = dataMan.entries.map((MapEntry mapEntry) => mapEntry.value).toList();
```

`mapEntry.key` is the type of `String` and `mapEntry.value` is the type of `AddictionDay`.

Comment: .map returns Map<K2, V2> which has no .toList defined

Comment: And .map is expecting MapEntry<K2, V2> as a parameter.. What am I missing?

Comment: error: The return type 'AddictionDay' isn't a 'MapEntry', as defined by anonymous closure.
error: The method 'toList' isn't defined for the class 'Map'.

Comment: You should include the code that shows the declaration of 'dataMan'.

Comment: `Map<String, AddictionDay> dataMan = new Map<String, AddictionDay>();`

Comment: I'm sorry. I though it was a list. I'll update my answer.

Comment: I got it working with `List<AddictionDay> addictionList = List<AddictionDay>.from(dataMan.entries.map((MapEntry mapEntry) => mapEntry.value).toList());` as it returned List<dynamic> which i couldn't explicitly recast to List<AddictionDay>